# Поменять группы символов двоичного кода местами побитовыми операциями со сдвигом (C#)

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

С помощью поразрядных логических операций выполнить над данными (не над строкой символов) следующее преобразование. Найти в двоичном коде максимальные по длине группы соседних одинаковых бит со значениями 0 и 1 и поменять эти группы местами со сдвигом при необходимости других бит между этими группами.

Пример:
0000000110010111 -> 1111100100000000

Comment: это ваше задание, но где ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как именно их поменять местами

Comment: добавь пример данных и что должно получиться

Comment: сделайте это с обычным массивом единиц и нулей, потом примените алгоритм на битовые операции.

Comment: _Пример: 0000000110010111 -> 1111100100000000_ - что-то я не понял по какому правилу тут преобразование

Comment: _Найти в двоичном коде максимальные по длине группы соседних одинаковых бит со значениями 0 и 1 и поменять эти группы местами со сдвигом при необходимости других бит между этими группами_ - вам понятно, что это означает? Мне нет. :(

Comment: @aepot, по описанию что-то вроде `00001111` -> `11110000`

Comment: @Grundy да, похоже на реверс, но не он.

Comment: @aepot, не реверс, а смена, то есть если будет не ровые интервалы они и останутся: `11100000` -> `00000111`

Comment: @Grundy: Всё правильно, начальная группа нулей уехала в конец, а финальная группа единиц в начало.

Comment: @VladD, но все еще непонятно как это к примеру в вопросе применить

Comment: @Grundy: По идее так: **0000000** 110010 **111** -> **111** 110010 **0000000**

Comment: @VladD, интересно, когда я считал единички в первом и втором числе - у меня разные количества получались :)

Comment: @VladD, можно длинные последовательности как-то битовыми операциями найти? Или в любом случае нужен будет цикл?

Comment: @Grundy: Может быть и можно, я не в курсе, и делал бы просто циклом.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте я не буду писать код (всё же это явно учебное задание), а подскажу идеи.

Для начала, вам нужно выяснить, где же находятся ваши максимальные по длине группы. Для этого имеет смысл пройтись по вашему числу (например, от старшего бита к младшему), и при проходе держать такую информацию:

- значение текущей группы (0 или 1 или неизвестно)
- длина текущей группы
- начало текущей группы
- начало и длина самой длинной группы нулевых бит (для пройденной части числа)
- начало и длина самой длинной группы единичных бит (для пройденной части числа)

После этого шага вы будете знать позиции групп, которые нужно обменять.
Получится как-то так:

```
[начальные биты] [первая группа] [биты между группами] [вторая группа] [финальные биты]
```

(начальные и финальные биты, а также биты между группами, могут оказаться нулевой длины).

В вашем итоговом числе должно быть так:

```
[начальные биты] [вторая группа] [биты между группами] [первая группа] [финальные биты]
```

Вам придётся перенести [начальные биты] как есть. Затем вам нужно будет подсчитать, на сколько бит нужно сдвинуть [вторую группу], чтобы она стала на своё место. Затем идут [биты между группами], их тоже придётся сдвинуть. Затем [первая группа] (с ней та же история), и без сдвига [финальные биты].

Какие элементарные операции вам понадобятся?

Выяснить, бит с данным индексом равен 0 или 1, можно, сравнив `(1 << bitNumber) & n` (где `n` — ваше число) с нулём.

Выделить группу можно при помощи аналогичной, более хитрой операции `(((1 << length) - 1) << startNumber) & n` (подумайте, почему). Для сдвига группы применяйте просто `<<` или `>>`.

Ну и для объединения кусков нужно просто `|`.

Дерзайте!